# Get site owners, full control user from all sites and subsites in a sharepoint 2013 site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reports, roles

Can you please give me a script or commands to get the all the list of users are having site owner and full control access from sites/sub-sites in a site collection.

I tried this but it is not giving all site owners and full control users.

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://sharepoint.com | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, ID, Author | Export-CSV D:\siteowners.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This PowerShell query is working fine. For the Full Control users you would need to query the permission groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication https://SharePoint.domain.com
$sites = $webapp | Get-SPSite -Limit All
$webs =  $sites | Get-SPWeb -Limit All
foreach ($web in $webs) {
    $users = $web.siteusers
    write-host "Processing " $web.url -foregroundcolor cyan
    write-host "Site Admins:" -foregroundcolor yellow
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        if ($user.IsSiteAdmin) {
            write-host $user.Name
        }
        #write-host $user.Name "IstSiteAdmin: " $user.isSiteAdmin
    }
    Write-host "Site Owners" -foregroundcolor green
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        if ($web.DoesUserHavePermissions($user,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::FullMask)) {
            write-host $user.Name
        }
    }
}
```

This Gives a list of site admins for the site to start with, then a list of users with the Full Control permission to the site.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = $web.AllUsers
```

in stead of

```
$users = $web.siteusers
```

It's faster